# TextBox inside checkbutton not wrapping

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, textbox, word-wrap

I have a listBox with a checkbox with inside a textblock:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbxtgbTab3"  FontSize="{StaticResource BUTTON_FONTSIZE}"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontWeight="Bold">
  <ToggleButton  Name="tgb4Tab3" Background="{x:Null}" Height="{StaticResource BUTTON_HEIGHT}" Click="ToggleButton_Click" Padding="0" FontWeight="Bold">
            <TextBlock Name="otb4Tab3" Text="4 - GESTIONE P.P." Margin="0" Background="Red" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
  </ToggleButton>
```

now the problem is that it doesn't wrap as you can see in the picture

[image]

--EDIT--

I have changed it like that

```
<ToggleButton  Name="tgb4Tab3"  Background="{x:Null}" Height="{StaticResource BUTTON_HEIGHT}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="175" Padding="0" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="3" IsChecked="false" Click="ToggleButton_Click" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0">
  <TextBlock Name="otb4Tab3" Text="4 - GESTIONE P.P." Margin="0" Fill="White" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</ToggleButton>
```

but no change

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be to specify the width of the ListBox or the width of the ToggleButton. If you don't specify the size whey will think they have infinite space to grow. Maybe if you show a complete example of the XAML can be easier to answer.

One solución could be:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="lbxtgbTab3"  FontSize="{StaticResource BUTTON_FONTSIZE}"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontWeight="Bold">
        <ToggleButton  Name="tgb4Tab3" Background="{x:Null}" Height="{StaticResource BUTTON_HEIGHT}" Click="ToggleButton_Click" Padding="0" FontWeight="Bold">
            <TextBlock Name="otb4Tab3" Text="4 - GESTIONE P.P." Margin="0" Background="Red" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </ToggleButton>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanx for helping. I am sorry I forgot to tell you that at runtime I set otb4Tab3.Width =  widthButton;

Comment: Change the size of tgb4Tab3 or lbxtgbTab3 and not otb4Tab3.
It's not a good practice to modify sizes and anything related with the UI in the code-behing. You can do almost everything only with XAML.